# Trying to add Notification Builder in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, download, notifications

Someone helps me out Pls

I wanted to implement a notification builder in my AsyncTask method for downloading files from the server. Notification that contains progress bar with incrementing base on file length, show download percentage and how many MB remain, with pause and resume, I try it but still notification not showing while downloading is doing in the background there is my code:

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                String folder = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/files/";

                File directory = new File(folder);


                if (!directory.exists()) {
                    directory.mkdirs();
                }

                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(folder + getIntent().getStringExtra("title") + ".mp4");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
            String type = "downloads";
            Update(type);

            View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toast_custom, findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));
            TextView text = layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("title") + "  - Downloaded Successfully!");
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code to show Notification and which android version os are you using ?

Comment: `mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MovieInfoActivity.this);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle("Download")
                    .setContentText("Download in progress")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo);
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(getIntent().getStringExtra("video_url"));`

Comment: My Phone is V9 pie

Comment: From android Oreo, you have to set NotificationChannel for builder. 
detail : https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels